# Undefined indexes in php - why?

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I have a question about indexes on arrays.

I have an array from a mysql result (PDO).

For example:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["carte_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["carte_titel"]=> string(16) "Pizza margherita" ["carte_cat"]=> string(1) "2" ["carte_text"]=> string(25) "Tomates Mozzarella Origan" } }
```

Then I need to create form elements:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM carte WHERE carte_id = ".$carte_id." LIMIT 1";
$this->result = $this->mysql_sql($sql);

var_dump($this->result); //This is the dump you can see above

$carte_titel = $this->result[0]['carte_titel']; //problem
$carte_text = $this->result[0]['carte_text']; //problem

$t= $this->html->create_hidden_input_element('carte_id',$carte_id);
$t.=$this->cat_option($this->result[0]['carte_cat']);
$t.= $this->html->create_input_element('carte_titel','text',$carte_titel,'Titre du menu sur la carte',50,80);
$t.= $this->html->create_input_element('carte_text','text',$carte_text,'Description du menu',50,80);
$t = $this->html->form_around_simple('index.php?action=update_sql&amp;table_name=carte','post',$t,'Mettre à jour');
```

Now - the code you can see above works fine. But I had to make a workaround for an index-defining-problem for $carte_titel and $carte_text. If I try to include $this->result[0]['carte_titel'] directly into html create_input_element I got an error telling me that it there is an undefined index. If I write my code like written above, I don't get this message.

My question is: what is the difference of indexes between the two calls on the array? It is the same array. I am forced to put the result into a second variable to use it in my html-element?

In other words:
Code that produces index-error

```
$t.= $this->html->create_input_element('carte_titel','text',$this->result[0]['carte_titel'],'Titre du menu sur la carte',50,80);
$t.= $this->html->create_input_element('carte_text','text',$this->result[0]['carte_text'],'Description du menu',50,80);
```

Code without index-error

```
$carte_titel = $this->result[0]['carte_titel']; //problem
$carte_text = $this->result[0]['carte_text']; //problem
$t.= $this->html->create_input_element('carte_titel','text',$carte_titel,'Titre du menu sur la carte',50,80);
$t.= $this->html->create_input_element('carte_text','text',$carte_text,'Description du menu',50,80);
```

Thanks to all for some explanation!

Comment: Can you add the code which generates the error?

Comment: I added some lines - hope it will help you to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few test only thing that comes to my mind to ask you for $t.=$this->cat_option($this->result[0]['carte_cat']); maybe you have in it something like $this->result = null or some things that clean up your variables... :S

i've tried few things and every time i get results

Comment: That is pretty funny. Your answer gave me the hint! I've got a function in the same class to create the select element. And I used in there the same $this->result for the categorie-options ^^ - and of course - this was replacing the data-array that was in before. A real stackoverflow! Thank you for helping my brain to think :-)